# What did House Rep Ryan Winkler mean when he used the term "Uncle Thomas"

Tags: united-states

> A Democratic lawmaker from Minnesota criticized Tuesday’s Supreme
>   Court decision on the Voting Rights Act by calling Justice Clarence
>   Thomas “Uncle Thomas,” then saying he didn’t know “Uncle Tom” was a
>   racist epithet.
>
> On his Twitter account Tuesday, state Rep. Ryan Winkler called the
>   justices’ 5-4 ruling striking down a part of the law racist, and the
>   work of “four accomplices to race discrimination and one Uncle
>   Thomas.” Justice Thomas, who is black, was one of the five justices in
>   the majority.

[source](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2013/jun/25/democratic-lawmaker-hits-justice-uncle-thomas/)

So what did [Rep Winkler](http://www.house.leg.state.mn.us/members/members.asp?id=15271) mean when he said that?

Note for the context of answering this question:

I am willing to accept any official or unofficial clarification, or absent that any generally reasonable alternative to the racial pejorative that is normally associated with the context. However, that alternative must make sense in the context of the statement.
I am not seeking to know the his actual meaning, just a plausible explanation for an alternative.

Comment: @BenCollins - The answer below is an opinion that the representative intended to use the term as the racial pejorative. The statement from Rep Winkler is denying that.  I am looking for more than the opinion of a poster that the rep actually meant this.  A reference to where he had used the same term before would do that.

Answer (score 11):

[Uncle Tom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom) is an epithet originating in the 1852 anti-slavery novel [Uncle Tom's Cabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom%27s_Cabin) by Harriet Beecher Stowe. As explained in Wikipedia, the literary consensus at the time the book was written in was that Tom was a good and noble character. However, the consensus has changed in modern times to be considered a racist epithet, particularly one who submits to the White man. At least part of the reason for this can be attributed to the multitude of adaptions for plays which re-characterized Uncle Tom, from Stowe's original vision. Its possible that Rep Winkler views Uncle Tom as a positive character, but since the opposite has been the prevailing opinion from the 1950s.

> The phrase "Uncle Tom" has also become an epithet for a person who is
>   slavish and excessively subservient to perceived authority figures,
>   particularly a black person who behaves in a subservient manner to
>   white people; or any person perceived to be a participant in the
>   oppression of their own group.

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom)

Rep Winkler was most likely acting on his party's orders to attack and criticize the supreme court justices, who made good on their previous threat to strike down the voting rights act, when he got carried away and went a bit too far. The democrats are angry about the decision because it allows many southern states to finally implement laws requiring a photo id to vote, which has met heavy opposition from democrats. It's also possible that that Rep Winkler committed political suicide and accidentally said what he believes.

Comment: The reference here to Harriet Beecher Stowe's original work is spot-on and accurate - an excellent answer. Stowe created the work, originally to have been titled *Life Among the Lowly*, as a denunciation of slavery. Page after page attest to the horrific and demeaning treatment of slaves, of families torn apart, never to meet again, at slave auctions etc. The character of Tom was an allegorical reference to Christ, who dies forgiving the people who are killing him.  (continued)

Comment: As you say, it was only the cheap adaptations and false plagiarisations of Stowe's text that created the term "Uncle Tom" as it is used today to mean a subservient black who kow-tows to the white man.  The original, when published caused a sensation and Lincoln accused HBS, after inviting her to the White House, of "starting the (civil) war". Both Leo Tolstoy and Charles Dicken read the work and both wrote letters of congratulation to Stowe. (And you didn't get commendations from those quarters for writing sentimental stuff about stereotypes).

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by the asker:

> The answer below is an opinion that the representative intended to use the term as the racial pejorative. The statement from Rep Winkler is denying that. I am looking for more than the opinion of a poster that the rep actually meant this. A reference to where he had used the same term before would do that.

Presumably "answer below" refers to [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/1624/4666).

[Ryan Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Winkler) is a white guy from a white state.  If we take his statement as true (which is of course disputed), then an easy explanation is that he heard one of his colleagues (DFL/Democrats in the Minnesota House) or staff use the term and then repeated it publicly without knowing what it meant.  Supporting this, note that he used the term incorrectly.  He said, "Uncle Thomas".  The actual term is "Uncle Tom."  Of course, he did so in referring to someone with the last name "Thomas."

There are several problems with trying to answer this question objectively.

1. Winkler was a minor politician.  While major politicians like Donald Trump have their every word quoted and parsed ad nauseam, most politicians don't.  In particular, very few state House members get quoted nationally.  There are only two statements that he made that have wide reach:
2. This one.
3. He's running for Attorney General of Minnesota in 2018.
4. I agree that his using the term previously could illuminate how he was using it here.  But what if he didn't use it previously in a public setting?  What does that tell us?

It is quite possible that he repeated something that he heard someone else say without really understanding what it meant.  The only person who could have told us what was really in his head was him, and of course, it is reasonable to be skeptical of his explanation.  The old joke has some basis in truth, "How do you tell when politicians are lying?  Their lips are moving."

The only real objective information we have is how the term is normally used.  Which is of course what the other answer explains.  It's not clear that additional objective information is available.

[Minnesota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota#Race_and_ancestry) was only 6.2% black in 2010 (last census).  Two of the cities that were partially in his district were about 7% black.  The [county](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hennepin_County,_Minnesota) was 8.95% black, but it also includes [Minneapolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minneapolis,_Minnesota#Demographics) which was about 18.6% black.  Going by the normal pattern of cities in the United States, this suggests that any other suburbs in his district would have been overwhelmingly white.  He may simply not have significant interaction with black people.

Answer (score -2):

An "Uncle Tom" is a pejorative generally used by one black against another. It refers to, according to the Urban Dictionary, "a black person, especially a man, considered by other black people to be subservient to or to curry favor with white people."

Evidently Rep. Ryan Winkler, who is an attorney from an urban area, has led a sheltered life if he claims to not know what it means.  'Uncle Tom' is an acceptable racial slur in Democratic circles.

Justice Clarence Thomas has been repeatedly called an "Uncle Tom" by many different Democrats, white and black, in order to smear him for being a Republican or making a decision they may disagree with.

Comment: `'Uncle Tom' is an acceptable racial slur in Democratic circles.` source?

Comment: @Federico - source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Uncle+Tom%22+liberal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) :)  First page includes links to examples.

Comment: is there any that is not a partisan website? or is it the word of one group against the word of the other?

Comment: What is an "acceptable racial slur"? I think that's an oxymoron.

Comment: Also this is a ridiculous answer to paint is as partisan...unless your point is that, in general, republican policies are racist to begin with--which is probably not your intent.

Comment: @Federico Alabama State Rep Alvin Holmes and Mississippi Rep Bennie Thompson have both called Justice Thomas an "U**** Tom" in recent years and have stood by their remarks (if they apologized I missed those links). Google searches are biased in favor of the more recent but I think I remember (it was a long time ago) Justice Thomas being called an "U**** Tom quite frequently during and just after his confirmation hearings.